# How to do direct assignment of string with a special character in C

Tags: c, string, eclipse, stm32

I find it quite useful that I can do this in C:

```
char *text;
text = "5 us";
```

However, when I try to do this

```
char *text;
text = "5 µs";
```

I get an extraneous character due to the source code encoding in UTF-8 in Eclipse (using CubeIDE). So the string looks like this in byte form:

```
0x35 0x20 0xC2 0xB5 0x73 0x00
```

I need the 0xC2 removed and I don't want to write a function to remove this character. I know I can configure Eclipse to handle my source code in US-ASCII. However, then I cannot save my file anymore because of the given assignment

```
text = "5 µs";
```

Eclipse won't save my file unless I remove the µ in my source code.

Is there maybe something like the following?

```
text = {'5', ' ', 181, 's', '0');
```

I just don't want to go through the hoops of creating a global string the pedestrian way. I want to preserve the elegance of a direct assignment.

Sorry if I don't use the proper C terms but I think you get the gist.

Comment: Are "Universal Character Names" aka UCN an option? `text = "5 \u00B5s"`

Comment: Which encoding do you want to use for the "µ"? It is not part of US-ASCII, so Eclipse's warning seems correct. Select some encoding that has this character.

Comment: @DavidRanieri If the execution character set is UTF-8, then the UCN would be translated the same way. Apparently the asker doesn't want the literal to be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: why do you want to limit yourself to ASCII when you can use UTF-8?

Comment: Note that the issue you are having is not really related to the encoding of the source file. Why exactly do you not want the UTF-8 encoded string? This might be a XY problem.

Comment: _I need the 0xC2 removed_ Why? It just makes the result garbage. With the string intact, it can printed, matched. With _just_ 0xB5, the string is nonsense. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 and look at the "Encoding" section

Comment: @CraigEstey It doesn't have to be nonsense. It could e.g. be ISO-8859-1 encoded. The issue here is that the question doesn't specify the expected encoding or why that encoding is required. It could be e.g. that they are trying to print the string on a terminal expecting that encoding instead of UTF-8.

Comment: Do you know what your execution character set is, that is, the character set used by the display system that shows your program's output?  It's probably not ASCII, because ASCII doesn't have the µ character at all.  It might be ISO-8859-1, aka "Latin 1".  Or it might be some version of Unicode, although it sounds like it's not (or you don't want it to be) the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode.

Comment: When you say you "get an extraneous character", does that mean the extraneous character is showing up in your program's output?

Comment: @user17732522 Well, the encoding _is_ UTF-8 based on the hex. Just removing 0xC2 does _not_ convert 0xB5 into some alternate encoding that keeps the char/codepoint as `µ`. (Well, it _does_ for ISO-8859-1 but that's just luck for 0xB5 or does it work for other codepoints as well?). It produces malformed UTF-8 because it's missing the start char (e.g. `11xxxxxx`). All following chars that are part of the same encoding are `10xxxxxx`. OP's editor sees the UTF-8 (e.g. `vi`) and prints correctly in a terminal window (e.g. `xterm`) so the output term is probably also UTF-8.

Comment: To put things further in perspective: the regular ASCII character 0xB5 covers the µ in my application, I don't need some fancy encoding. Using the regular ASCII standard set is all I need with the exception of the µ. This is for an electronics application where I use seconds (s), milliseconds (ms), microseconds (µs) and nanoseconds (ns). And I am annoyed to see so many applications nowadays where people replace µs with us.

Comment: @David Ranieri, I tried your suggestion and the weird thing is that the compiled code still shows the 0xC2. After changing all µ's to \u00B5, I was able to turn the encoding in Eclipse to US-ASCII. I made sure I changed some other characters in the same string just to see if I made a mistake somewhere else, but nope it keeps adding the 0xC2.

Comment: UTF-8 fancy encoding? UTF-8 ist today's most supported standard, you should use unless there is really good reason not to use it. µ is not part of ASCII, so you have to use at least ISO-8858-1 (latin1). But then you will need to tell your text editor that your encoding is ISO-8858-1, then it will put µ in the correct encoding when you type the character.

Comment: @Pablo The encoding of the source file is not relevant.

Comment: @user17732522: Please make this an answer.  There are so many comments by people who think utf-8 is the only character set in the world.     The IDE described in the question uses GCC so -fexec-charset= is all the OP needs, (plus maybe the information that they need to choose between 8859-1 or 1252).

Comment: @Hansel *To put things further in perspective: the regular ASCII character 0xB5 covers the µ in my application, I don't need some fancy encoding.* Others have said this, but it bears repeating: `µ` is *not* part of the "regular ASCII encoding".  You're going to need to figure out which non-ASCII encoding you're actually using (8859-1, Windows CP 1252, or something else).  You may not need a "fancy encoding", but as David Zentgraf [explains well](https://kunststube.net/encoding/), you're *always* using *some* encoding.

Comment: @Hansel Also, some day, when you're ready to, you might want to take another look at UTF-8.  It may be "fancy", but it really is a very nice and usable compromise when it comes to handling multinational characters in computer programs today.  Something else to read on this subject is the "[UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)" manifesto.

Comment: @TomV Despite its basic nature, this has been an instructive thread.  I thought I knew a lot about i18n, but I had never even heard of the `-fexec-charset` option.  This needs to be better known!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`µ` does not exist in the ASCII character set.

There are many single-byte encodings extending ASCII with `µ` mapped to `0xB5`, for example ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-3, ISO-8859-8, Windows-1252, and so on.

It is not clear which one you'd want, but most likely either ISO-8859-1, aka latin1, or Windows-1252. Have a look at the Wikipedia pages for the encodings if you are unsure.

If the issue is only that the strings are not printed correctly, the best solution would be to set the outputting device to UTF-8.

If not possible, you can tell the compiler the execution character set you want, which is the character set to which string literals are translated.

GCC defaults the execution character set to UTF-8, but that can be changed with the `-fexec-charset=` flag (with one of the encodings given above as argument). That does however have global effects and will mess up output on devices expecting a different encoding, such as UTF-8.

Also note that the encoding of the source file is not relevant, nor does the result change if you use a universal character name. The characters in the string literal are always translated to the execution character set.

Comment: Excellent answer.  The `-fexec-charset` option needs to be better known!

Comment: @SteveSummit As I am trying to hint in the answer, I am not exactly sure what other effects besides the literal encoding this flag may have. Ultimately I think it is safer to stay with the UTF-8 default internally and transcode output to a different encoding if that is necessary. But that probably requires a library like iconv to do properly.

Comment: Under Linux and MacOS it's easy, because [UTF-8 really is everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/).  I get the impression that Windows folks don't always have it so easy, though.  I don't know what-all `-fexec-charset` does, either, but I'd like to investigate it.  It sounds like it may be an important part of the answer, at least under some circumstances.  People don't always think about character sets and encodings correctly, and it's especially easy to miss the distinction between the source and execution sets.  But `-fexec-charset` makes that distinction quite explicit!

Comment: @user17732522, many thanks for solution and the detailed explanation. Using compiler flag -fexec-charset=ISO-8859-1 did the trick.